# positiong a textView on the screen

Tags: android, textview

I want to place a `TextView` `below the red zone` in the following image but I just can do it.
[image: enter image description]

Until now I have the following layout:

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabhost1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 >
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/layout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="0 restaurant trouves"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:textSize="15dip"
android:textColor="#000000"
/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone tell what is the right code for placing the textView below the red tab?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is everything you mentioned in your post in one XML file? It looks like its not well formatted and your screenshot does not make it clear too, but I am giving it a try.

It seems that your TextView is not even inside the RelativeLayout.You are closing it's tag before declaring your TextView, so you have to move it into RelativeLayout.
And I don't know if you want to show this TextView in every single Tab. But if it is like that, you could try the following scheme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="TextView" />

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

There are two TextViews in this example. One is centered and the other one is drawn below of the first with: `android:layout_below="@id/textView1"`.

Now you have to do this with your Views...

Comment: I don't really know what have you done there, but NO, it is not working.Let me make it clear:I have two tabs(Liste and Plan) in the white space below them I want to put that textView!!!!!!!!

Comment: And Yes, i want it to be visibile in both Liste and Plan tabs!

Answer (score 0):

your layout code doesn't seem to have everything you have on the screenshot, so I'm not sure how your red set of tabs work but here's a mockup with a simple view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="0 restaurant trouves"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That will give you this: (eclipse screenshot, no tabs in widget)

[image]